# Understanding multiple indexing

Tags: assembly, memory-address

IEC 60880 states that: "multiple substitutions or multiple indexing within a
single machine instruction should be avoided". However, as far as I know, on x86 multiple indexing is not even possible. Address is always a combination of base, index and offset. Obviously, there is something I don't understand.

What is multiple indexing regarding to x86?

Why it is bad?

UPDATE: Maybe this rule doesn't apply to x86 at all. Still it would be nice to know what it applies to. Any reference to multiple indexing regarding any other architecture would be appreciated.

Comment: What is "IEC 60880"? Can you provide a link?

Comment: IEC 60880 appears to concern instrumentation and control systems for nuclear power plants; what on earth does that have to do with x86?

Comment: Sorry, I only have printed copy.

Comment: Part of our ICS is written in x86 assembly.

Comment: Does it say it only applies to x86?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is in an "Assembler" section, but there's nothing regading architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some DSPs can have very complicated instructions which do several operations at once. E.g. from TI's TMS320C55:

```
btst    #0Fh, *AR0+, TC1
:: mov *AR5+ << #16, AC3
```

This is a parallel instruction which does a bit test at the same time as a move, and increments both data pointers as part of the operation. I guess this could be what they're talking about in "multiple indexing".

In x86, the closest match is probably the "string move" instruction (`movs`) which operates on `esi` and `edi` at the same time. Or it might be something like `push dword ptr [esp+4]` which both accesses the stack and increments the stack pointer.

I have no idea what they mean by "substitutions". Maybe check if they define any of these terms anywhere.